# How to add an emoji font to Heroku and replace the dejavu defaults?

Tags: heroku, fonts, emoji, buildpack, puppeteer

I'm trying to use emojione-apple.ttf from https://github.com/emojione/emojione/tree/master/extras/fonts on Heroku because the default font on Heroku (dejavu) doesn't have all the emoji.

I added the fonts on the ~/.fonts folder with this buildpack : https://github.com/GautierT/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

When i render an HTML page to PDF with https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer it's seems that it's still dejavu fonts and not the emojione.

[image]

(Very low quality, weird "glasses" and "gear" emoji)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the android variant of emojione's font with degrees of success for [browserless](https://browserless.io/). I'm not sure what linux distro Heroku uses for their service, but you might have to consider an alternative provider if it's limited (Firebase functions and AWS Lambdas have similar constraints).

Comment: I think I can do that with heroku but I'm not very good on Linux so I'm failing to replace dejavu by emojione.. heroku let's you add package with apt-get so it should be possible

Comment: Btw your FAQ is not responsive. I will look into your service. Might be interested!

Answer (score 0):

I created a buildpack to add native emoji support for a Heroku-18 stack (you can grab it here https://github.com/SimonBriche/heroku-buildpack-emoji-support) with the limitation of the emojis supported by the DejaVu font.
Long story short, the DejaVu font takes precedence over NotoColorEmoji for the emojis that it knows.

There is no clean workaround for that, besides replacing DejaVu by an other font that doesn't know any emojis (the best candidate would be Bitstream Vera) but it could lead to other (worst ?) side effects...
More details can be found in the readme of the repo.

HTH